# The IE file download dialog - how to hide the from field?

Tags: internet-explorer

I need to hide the **From** field on the standard Internet Explorer's file download dialog. 
This is necessary for security reasons.
The picture to look at is at http://www.filedropper.com/howtohidefrom

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. And it's best that way.

Comment: You mean it is best to expose the location from where on the server the file is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This is built into the dialog box. You can't remove it, without lots of IE hacking, which will produce its own set of security problems.

Comment: Any suggestions on an alternative?